# Why is perldoc failing here?

Tags: perl, perldoc

Downloaded ActiveState Perl V5.22.3 (tried V5.24, same result) and I can't get perldoc to run! perldoc responds with 'Invalid parameter - -R'.

Here's my command window:

[image: Showing current PATH setting and perldoc oddness with this '-R' invalid option]

I'm not having issues running scripts - just perldoc.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What does `where perldoc` reveal?

Comment: Posting an image of text is a terrible way to report a problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a bug in perldoc version 3.27. See this posting on the ActiveState site for a workaround.

https://community.activestate.com/node/20823

> grahams `ActiveState Staff`
>   Wed, 2017-02-15 11:09
>
> This is confirmed in 5.24.1 and 5.22.3.
>
> It's happening in the section where perldoc hands off to the local equivalent of nroff. On Win32 and Win64, a bug is allowing perldoc to get into a block of code intended to fix a problem on Debian Linux ([bugs.debian.org/758689](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=758689)). This block won't run on Windows, so the handoff to pod2text fails.
>
> ```
> C:\> perldoc CGI
> Invalid parameter - -R
> ```
>
> Workaround 1: Bypass perldoc and go directly to pod2text. Give pod2text the full path to the pod file.
>
> ```
> pod2text C:\Perl\libCGI.pod
> ```
>
> Workaround 2: Bypass the pager in perldoc.
>
> ```
> perldoc -T CGI
> ```
>
> Workaround 3: Use the previous release of 5.22.2 which has an older perldoc.

Comment: Good answer. Well caught.

Comment: Thanks a bunch...
And I'll not post images describing problems